# How to pass a method as callback to a Windows API call?

Tags: delphi, winapi

I'd like to pass a method of a class as callback to a WinAPI function. Is this possible and if yes, how?

Example case for setting a timer:

```
TMyClass = class
public
  procedure TimerProc(Wnd:HWND; uMsg:DWORD; idEvent:PDWORD; dwTime:DWORD);
  procedure DoIt;
end;
[...]
procedure TMyClass.DoIt;
begin
  SetTimer(0, 0, 8, @TimerProc);  // <-???- that's what I want to do (last param)
end;
```

Thanks for your help!

**Edit**: The goal is to specify a method of this class as callback. No procedure outside the class.

**Edit2**: I appreciate all your help but as long as the method has no "TMyClass." in front of its name it is not what I am searching for. I used to do it this way but wondered if could stay fully in the object oriented world. Pointer magic welcome.

Comment: yes it is possible in c# using delegates...I dont know whether there are delegates present in delphi/winapi

Answer (score 9, accepted):

[Madshi](http://www.madshi.net/) has a [MethodToProcedure](http://help.madshi.net/MethodToProc.htm) procedure. It's in the "madTools.pas" which is in the "madBasic" package. If you use it, you should change the calling convention for "TimerProc" to stdcall and DoIt procedure would become,

```
TMyClass = class
private
  Timer: UINT;
  SetTimerProc: Pointer;
[...]

procedure TMyClass.DoIt;
begin
  SetTimerProc := MethodToProcedure(Self, @TMyClass.TimerProc);
  Timer := SetTimer(0, 0, 8, SetTimerProc);
end;
// After "KillTimer(0, Timer)" is called call:
// VirtualFree(SetTimerProc, 0, MEM_RELEASE);
```

I've never tried but I think one could also try to duplicate the code in the "classses.MakeObjectInstance" for passing other procedure types than TWndMethod.

Comment: Googling for MethodToProcedure delivered several implementations of a function named MethodToProcedure which does the job. If I understand it right it creates a wrapper function on the fly which passes the hidden self parameter. Attention though: the example above leaks memory. The returned pointer needs to be freed.

Comment: Interesting, I haven't come across that before!  Could you edit your comment to indicate it needs to be freed with VirtualFree, as the MethodToProcedure link mentions, please?

Comment: Done (modified the answer). I also took the liberty to introduce a variable to hold the timer id to be able to call KillTimer later on...

Answer (score 6):

Which version of Delphi are you using?

In recent ones you can use static class methods for this:

```
TMyClass = class
public
  class procedure TimerProc(Wnd:HWND; uMsg:DWORD; idEvent:PDWORD; dwTime:DWORD); stdcall; static;
  procedure DoIt;
end;
[...]
procedure TMyClass.DoIt;
begin
  SetTimer(0, 0, 8, @TimerProc);  
end;
```

Comment: This is the way to go in recent versions of Delphi!

Comment: @TLama - Class procedures does not have access to a specific instance, this is not what OP asks for. See poster's [comment](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2787887/how-to-pass-a-method-as-callback-to-a-windows-api-call/2788091#comment2823676_2788023) to Lieven's answer,

Answer (score 2):

The TimerProc procedure should be a **standard procedure, not a method pointer.**

> A method pointer is really a pair of
>   pointers; the first stores the address
>   of a method, and the second stores a
>   reference to the object the method
>   belongs to

### Edit

This might be as much OOP as you are going to get it. All the nasty stuff is hidden from anyone using your TMyClass.

```
unit Unit2;

interface

type
  TMyClass = class
  private
    FTimerID: Integer;
    FPrivateValue: Boolean;
  public
    constructor Create;
    destructor Destroy; override;
    procedure DoIt;
  end;

implementation

uses
  Windows, Classes;

var
  ClassList: TList;

constructor TMyClass.Create;
begin
  inherited Create;
  ClassList.Add(Self);
end;

destructor TMyClass.Destroy;
var
  I: Integer;
begin
  I := ClassList.IndexOf(Self);
  if I <> -1 then
    ClassList.Delete(I);
  inherited;
end;

procedure TimerProc(Wnd:HWND; uMsg:DWORD; idEvent:PDWORD; dwTime:DWORD); stdcall;
var
  I: Integer;
  myClass: TMyClass;
begin
  for I := 0 to Pred(ClassList.Count) do
  begin
    myClass := TMyClass(ClassList[I]);
    if myClass.FTimerID = Integer(idEvent) then
      myClass.FPrivateValue := True;
  end;
end;

procedure TMyClass.DoIt;
begin
  FTimerID := SetTimer(0, 0, 8, @TimerProc);  // <-???- that's what I want to do (last param)
end;

initialization
  ClassList := TList.Create;

finalization
  ClassList.Free;

end.
```

**Edit:** *(as mentioned by glob)*

Don't forget to add the stdcall calling convention.

Comment: don't forget to include "stdcall" as per Lieven's example; it's important and easily forgotten :)

Comment: Well yes I know how this is done. But that is what I do not want to do! I don't want to leave my class and also need to access other members of it (without using global variables or the like).

Comment: Then the answer is that unfortunatly it is not possible to add a method pointer as a callback to a Windows API call.

Answer (score 1):

**Response to your second edit:**

If you want a reply that includes a pointer to a `TMyClass` instance, you may be out of luck.  Fundamentally, the procedure Windows will call has a certain signature and is not an object method.  You cannot *directly* work around that, not even with `__closure` or `procedure of object` magic, except as described below and in other answers.  Why?

- Windows has no knowledge of it being an object method, and wants to call a procedure with a specific signature.
- The pointer is no longer a simple pointer - it has two halves, the object instance and the method.  It needs to save the `Self`, as well as the method.

By the way, I don't understand what is wrong with a short dip outside the object-oriented world.  Non-OO code is not necessarily dirty *if* used well.

**Original, pre-your-edit answer:**

It's not possible exactly as you are trying to do it.  The method that `SetTimer` wants must exactly follow the `TIMERPROC` signature - see the [MSDN documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms644907(v=VS.85).aspx).  This is a simple, *non-object* procedure.

However, the method `TMyClass.DoIt` is an object method.  It actually has two parts: the object on which it is called, and the method itself.  In Delphi, this is a `"procedure of object"` or a `"closure"` ([read about procedural types here](http://docs.embarcadero.com/products/rad_studio/delphiAndcpp2009/HelpUpdate2/EN/html/devcommon/proceduraltypes_xml.html)).  So, the signatures are not compatible, and you cannot store the object instance, which you need in order to call an object method.  (There are also calling convention problems - standard Delphi methods are implemented using the `fastcall` convention, whereas `TIMERPROC` specifies `CALLBACK` which, from memory, is a macro that expands to `stdcall`.  Read more about [calling conventions and especially fastcall](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X86_calling_conventions#fastcall).)

So, what do you do?  You need to **map your non-object-oriented callback into object-oriented code**.

There are several ways, and the simplest is this:

If you only have one timer ever, then you know that when your timer callback is called it is that specific timer that fired.  Save a method pointer in a variable that is of type `procedure of object` with the appropriate signature.  See the Embarcadero documentation link above for more details.  It will probably look like:

```
type TMyObjectProc = procedure of object;
var pfMyProc : TMyObjectProc;
```

Then, initialise `pfMyProc` to `nil`.  In `TMyClass.DoIt`, set `pfMyProc` to `@DoIt` - that is, it is now pointing at the `DoIt` procedure in the context of *that specific* `TMyClass` instantiation.  Your callback can then call that method.

(If you're interested, class variables that are of a procedural type like this are how event handlers are stored internally.  The `OnFoo` properties of a VCL object are pointers to object procedures.)

Unfortunately this procedural architecture is not object-oriented, but it's how it has to be done.

Here's what some full code might look like (I'm not at a compiler, so it may not work as written, but it should be close):

```
type TMyObjectProc = procedure of object;
var pfMyProc : TMyObjectProc;

initialization
  pfMyProc = nil;

procedure MyTimerCallback(hWnd : HWND; uMsg : DWORD; idEvent : PDWORD; dwTime : DWORD); stdcall;
begin
  if Assigned(pfMyProc) then begin
    pfMyProc(); // Calls DoIt, for the object that set the timer
    pfMyProc = nil;
  end;
end;

procedure TMyClass.MyOOCallback;
begin
  // Handle your callback here
end;

procedure TMyClass.DoIt;
begin
  pfMyProc = @MyOOCallback;
  SetTimer(0, 0, 8, @ MyTimerCallback);
end;
```

Another way would be to take advantage of the fact your timer has a unique ID.  Save a mapping between the timer ID and the the object.  In the callback, convert from the ID to the pointer, and call the object's method.

**Edit:** I've noticed a comment to another answer suggesting using the address of your object as the timer ID.  This will work, but is a potentially dangerous hack if you end up having two objects at the same address at different times, and you don't call `KillTimer`.  I've used that method but don't personally like it - I think the extra bookkeeping of keeping a (timer ID, object pointer) map is better.  It really comes down to personal style, though.

Comment: After-my-edit-comment: Yes I know how this works and about the two pointers. My knowledge currently stops at this point, not knowing if I could somehow make use of these pointers to fake a plain method. I think Sertac's answer is going in the right direction. I googled a bit and it seems there is some assembler involved in handling the hidden self-pointer. Seems dirty. But could work.

Comment: I haven't come across Madshi's method before - looks very cool.

Answer (score 1):

I've used MakeObjectInstance a few times to do the same.
Here's an article on the subject:
    [How to use a VCL class member-function as a Win32 callback](http://edn.embarcadero.com/article/22225)

Answer (score 0):

```
TMyClass = class
public
  procedure DoIt;
  procedure DoOnTimerViaMethod;
end;

var MyReceiverObject: TMyClass;

[...]

procedure TimerProc(Wnd:HWND; uMsg:DWORD; idEvent:PDWORD; dwTime:DWORD); stdcall:
begin
  if Assigned(MyReceiverObject) then 
    MyReceiverObject.DoOnTimerViaMethod;
end;

procedure TMyClass.DoIt;
begin
  MyReceiverObject := Self;
  SetTimer(0, 0, 8, @TimerProc);  // <-???- that's what I want to do (last param)
end;
```

Not perfect. Watch for the threads, variable overwriting etc. But it does the job.