# Using procedure in structured data type as callback for C library (GTK+3)

Tags: gtk3, freepascal

I'm trying to use procedures within a structured data type as callback functions for a program using GTK+3 as its toolkit in FreePascal. (The GTK+3 bindings I have were generated by the gir2pascal tool (http://wiki.freepascal.org/gir2pascal))

In the example below, I use advanced records, but I would definitely consider classes or objects if it works better/at all with them.

The problem that occurs is that when the callback procedure is called, it cannot access anything else within its own record. It seems to "forget" where it comes from.

For instance, in the example below I have the integer myRecord.myInt, that I can set and retrieve happily by calling the procedure myRecord.testProcedure. However when testProcedure is used as a C callback (when I click the button), I will receive some number (e.g. 30976), but not 7.

```
{$MODESWITCH ADVANCEDRECORDS}
uses gobject2, gtk3, math;

type
  myRecord=record
    public
      myInt: Integer;
      procedure testProcedure; cdecl;
  end;

  procedure myRecord.testProcedure; cdecl;
  begin
    WriteLn(myInt);
  end;

var
  recordInstance: myRecord;
  button, win: PGtkWidget;
begin
  SetExceptionMask([exDenormalized, exInvalidOp, exOverflow,
    exPrecision, exUnderflow, exZeroDivide]); {this is needed for GTK not to crash}

  gtk_init(@argc, @argv);

  win:=gtk_window_new(GTK_WINDOW_TOPLEVEL);

  recordInstance.myInt:=7;

  button:=gtk_button_new;

  {The following does not work. The procedure will run when the button is
  clicked; it will print some number, but not the content of recordInstance.myInt}
  g_signal_connect_data(button, 'clicked',
    TGCallback(@recordInstance.testProcedure), nil, nil, 0);

  {add button to window}
  gtk_container_add(PGtkContainer(win), button);

  gtk_widget_show_all(win);

  {Test call to recordInstance.testProcedure to see that it outputs
  '7' correctly}
  recordInstance.testProcedure;

  gtk_main;
end.
```

When I try to use Classes or Objects instead of an Advanced Record, I receive error messages of the kind

```
"<procedure variable type of procedure of object;CDecl>" to "<procedure variable type of procedure;CDecl>"
```

What ways are there of using a structured data type with a procedure to use as a C callback as in the example above (if any)?

Comment: I guess that C has no way to use a method as a callback. The method call has to be converted to an ordinary procedure call. See [How to pass a method as callback to a Windows API call?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/2787887/576719).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

class static methods are compatible with procedures. But they also have the disadvantage that they don't have a reference to the data of the object.

```
{$mode delphi}

type
  myRecord=record
    public
      myInt: Integer;
      class procedure testProcedure; cdecl;static;
  end;

  tproctype = procedure; cdecl;

class procedure myrecord.testProcedure; cdecl;static;
begin
end;

var x : tproctype;
    y : myrecord;
begin
 x:=y.testprocedure;
end.
```

compiles, but the usage is sterile, since if it maps to plain C, it doesn't have (implicit) OO properties.